# Cannot find validation in html page

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<head>
<title> Add User page</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<form name='f2' action="insert_ac.php" method="post" >
<script src="validation.js" type="javascript/text"></script> 
</head>
<body  onload="firstfocus();">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
 <tr>
 <td> First Name</td><td > : </td>
 <td>  <input type='text' name='fname' id='fid' size="50" style="background-color:#abcddd; height:18px;" value='' maxlength="100" onblur="fname_validation(5,12);">    </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
<td> Last Name</td><td> : </td>
 <td> <input type='text' name='lname' id='lid' size="50" style="background-color:#abcddd; height:18px; "value='' maxlength="100" onblur="lname_validation(5,12);"> </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
<td> Gender</td><td> : </td>
<td> <input type='radio' name='gend' id='m' value='M' checked>Male <input type='radio' name='gend' id='f' value='F'>Female</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Phone Number</td><td> : </td>
 <td> <input type='number_format' name='phone' id='phno'size="50" style="background-color:#abcddd; height:18px; " value=''onblur="allnumeric();"></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td> Work Experiance</td><td> : </td>
   <td><select name="exp" onblur="expselect();">
   <option > Select One</option>
   <option selected="" value="Default"> Select One </option>
   <option value="F"> Fresher </option>
   <option value="E"> Experiance</option>
   </select></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>User Name</td><td>:</td><td> <input type='txt' name='uname' id='uid'size="50" style="background-color:#abcddd; height:18px; " value=''onblur="userid_validation(5,10);">   </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>Password</td><td>:</td><td> <input type='password' name='pwd' id='pid' size="50" style="background-color:#abcddd; height:18px; " value=''onblur="passid_validation(7,12);"></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td width="84"><input name="enter" class="btn_login" type="submit" value="Submit"  onsubmit="alert('Data stored successfully');"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="cancle" class="btn_login" type="reset" value="Cancle" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I included the external javascript file using script tag but the validations are not working.

This is my external javascript code  which was saved as validation.js and i am unable to find errors in it please help me.

```
// After form loads focus will go to first name field.  
function firstfocus()  
{  
var fname = document.f2.fname.focus();  
return true;  
}  
// This function will validate First name  
function fname_validation(mx,my)  
{  
var fname = document.f2.fname;  
var fname_len = fname.value.length; 
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
 if (fname_len == 0 || fname_len >= my || fname_len < mx)  
{  
alert("First Name should not be empty / length be between "+mx+" to "+my);  
fname.focus();  
return false;  
      if(fname.value.match(letters)) 
    {  
// Focus goes to next field i.e.Last Name  
 document.f2.lname.focus();  
return true;  
 }  
}  
 }

 // This function will validate Last name  
function lname_validation(mx,my)  
 {  
 var lname = document.f2.lname;  
 var lname_len = lname.value.length; 
 var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;    
 if (lname_len == 0 || lname_len >= my || lname_len < mx)  
 {  
  alert("Last Name should not be empty / length be between "+mx+" to "+my);  
  lname.focus();  
    return false;  
    if(fname.value.match(letters)) 
    {  
    // Focus goes to next field i.e.Phone Number  
     document.f2.phone.focus();  
   return true;  
   }  
   }  
   }

  // This function will validate Phone Number.  
  function allnumeric()  
   {   
   var phone = document.f2.phone;  
     var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;  
     if(phone.value.match(numbers))  
     {  
    // Focus goes to next field i.e. Experiance.  
   document.f2.exp.focus();  
    return true;  
   }  
   else  
   {  
   alert('Phone Number must have numeric characters only');  
   phone.focus();  
   return false;  
   }  
   }    
   // This function will select Experiance.  
    function expselect()  
    {  
   var exp = document.f2.exp;  
   if(exp.value == "Default")  
   {  
   alert('Select your Experiance from the list');  
   exp.focus();  
   return false;  
   }  
   else  
   {  
   // Focus goes to next field i.e. Username Code.  
   document.f2.uname.focus();  
   return true;  
  }  
  }  

  // This function will validate User Name.  
  function allLetter()  
   {   
   var uname = document.f2.uname;  
   var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
  if(uname.value.match(letters))  
   {  
   // Focus goes to next field i.e. Password.  
    document.f2.pwd.focus();  
     return true;  
    }  
    else  
     {  
     alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');  
    uname.focus();  
     return false;  
     }  
     }  

    // This function will validate Password.  
   function passid_validation(mx,my)  
   {  
   var passid = document.registration.passid;  
    var passid_len = passid.value.length;  
   if (passid_len == 0 ||passid_len >= my || passid_len < mx)  
    {  
    alert("Password should not be empty / length be between "+mx+" to "+my);  
     passid.focus();  
     return false;  
     }  
     }
```

Comment: Please add the full HTML code of a sample page. Your `javascript` looks unsuspicious, but trying a working example in a browser will quickly point to the cause of it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the java script file and now i can find validations in my form...

Thanks for your help..

here i am sharing my code...

HTML code

```
   <form name='f1' action="insert_ac.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm();" >
     <tr>
   <td height="25" height="25" colspan="2" bgcolor="#EC6921" class="form_heading">Add User Form</td>
</tr>
                     <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"   height="28" class="form_txt"> First Name:</td> 
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">  <input type='text' name='fname' id='fid' size="50" style="height:18px;" value='' maxlength="100" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="28" class="form_txt"> Last Name:</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" > <input type='text' name='lname' id='lid' size="50" style=" height:18px; "value='' maxlength="100" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="28" class="form_txt"> Gender:</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" > <input type='radio' name='gend' id='m' value='M' checked>Male <input type='radio' name='gend' id='f' value='F'>Female</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="28" class="form_txt"> Phone Number:</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" > <input type='number_format' name='phone' id='phno'size="50" style=" height:18px; " value=''></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="28" class="form_txt"> Work Experiance:</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" ><select name="exp" >
                            <option selected="" value="Default"> Select One </option>
                            <option value="Fresher"> Fresher </option>
                            <option value="Experiance"> Experiance</option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="28" class="form_txt">User Name:</td><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> <input type='txt' name='uname' id='uid'size="50" style=" height:18px; " value=''></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="28" class="form_txt">Password:</td><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> <input type='password' name='pwd' id='pid' size="50" style=" height:18px; " value=''></td>
                </tr>
                     </table>
        <table align="center">
                <tr>
                  <td ><input name="enter" class="btn_login" type="submit" value="Submit" align="center"><input name="cancle" class="btn_login" type="reset" value="Cancle" valign="right" /></td>
                </tr>
   </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </form>


   </body>
  </html>
```

Here is my java script file which is working fine....

```
   var RE = /^.+@.+\..{3}$/;
   var RE1 = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var RE2 = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
     var RE3 = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;
    function validateForm()
    {
      if (document.f1.fname.value == "")
      {
    window.alert("first name should NOT BE empty");
    document.f1.fname.focus();
    return false;
   }
   else
    if (RE1.test(document.f1.fname.value) == false)
    {
      alert("Invalid first name\n\
      ");
       return false;
     }
     else
    if (document.f1.fname.value.length < 3)
     {
    window.alert("Firstname must have atleast Three characters");
    document.f1.fname.focus();
    return false;
    }
     else
     if (document.f1.lname.value == "")
    {
    window.alert("Lastname should not be empty");
    document.f1.lname.focus();
    return false;
     }
    else
   if (RE1.test(document.f1.lname.value) == false)
    {
    alert("Invalid last name");
    return false;
    }
    else
     if (document.f1.lname.value.length < 4)
     {
    window.alert("Lastname must have atleast four characters");
    document.f1.lname.focus();
    return false;
     }
     else
     if (document.f1.lname.value == "")
    {
    window.alert("Last name should not be empty");
    document.f1.lname.focus();
    return false;
      }
    else
     if (document.f1.phone.value == "")
     {
    window.alert("phne no should NOT BE empty");
    document.f1.phone.focus();
    return false;
     } else
     if (RE3.test(document.f1.phone.value) == false)
     {
    alert("Invalid phone number");
    document.f1.phone.focus();
    return false;
     }
     else
     if (document.f1.exp.selectedIndex == 0)
     {
        window.alert("please select work experiance ");
       return false;
     }
     else
      if (document.f1.uname.value == "")
    {
    window.alert("UserName should not be empty");
    document.f1.uname.focus();
    return false;
    }
    else
    if (RE1.test(document.f1.uname.value) == false)
    {
    window.alert("Invalid userName ");
    document.f1.uname.focus();
    return false;
    }

    else
    if (document.f1.pwd.value == "")
    {
    window.alert("password should not be empty");
    document.f1.pwd.focus();
    return false;
     }
    else
   if (document.f1.pwd.value.length < 6)
    {
    window.alert("password must have atleast six characters");
    document.f1.pwd.focus();
    return false;
     }

    else
    {
    window.alert("User has been added successfully.");
    return true;
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference the .js if its not in the same folder as html

EDIT
`function fname_validation(mx,my)

{`

is missing a closing bracket!

Comment: are you sure OP reference of js is wrong, if no this should be a comment!

Comment: just i changed the <script type="text/javascript"> and verified that the jsfile available in the same folder

Comment: changed my answer pls check!!

Comment: still i am not getting the output.

Comment: var fname=  document.getElementById('fname').value

Comment: please find the html page above    I already uploaded the html  page source code

Comment: pls include the suggestion instead of what u have given

Comment: Actually I want to check the fields are  filled or not and want to store the values in database.                                                                while clicking the submit button with out filling the textfields it doesn't show any alert message to me . it simply stay on the same page with out doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

try to change `<script type="javascript/text">` to `<script type="text/javascript">`
and double check the reference of your js file. Also, put an alert check to determine if it is really going through the firstFocus() function.

Comment: I changed that one but i am unable to get validation in that html page

Comment: Help me to find out solution.